# Flag the first occurrence of a number and all rows after

Tags: r

I have a `df` in R that tracks the status whether an individual is single (0), married (1), or divorced (99) overtime.

```
ID <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5)
STATUS <- c("0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "99", "99", "1", "0", "1")
df <- data.frame(ID, STATUS)
df
```

I would like to create a new variable which flags the first time the individual is divorced (STATUS = 99) and any rows after that point. For example under the `STATUS` column, ID 1 was single for three periods, then was divorced for three periods column, and later got married again. The "flag" column flags the first 99 that appears and all events after that row for each `ID`.

The final product should look like:

```
  ID STATUS    FLAG
   1      0      0
   1      0      0
   1      0      0
   1      1      0
   1      1      0
   1      1      0
   1     99      1
   1     99      1
   1      1      1
   5      0      0
   5      1      0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility using `dplyr`:

```
df %>%
 group_by(ID) %>%
 mutate(flag = +(row_number() >= min(which(STATUS == 99))))

      ID STATUS  flag
   <dbl> <fct>  <dbl>
 1    1. 0         0.
 2    1. 0         0.
 3    1. 0         0.
 4    1. 1         0.
 5    1. 1         0.
 6    1. 1         0.
 7    1. 99        1.
 8    1. 99        1.
 9    1. 1         1.
10    5. 0         0.
11    5. 1         0.
```

Or a possibility based on the solution from @markus:

```
df %>%
 group_by(ID) %>%
 mutate(flag = cummax(STATUS == 99))
```

Or with `base R`:

```
df$flag <- ave(df$STATUS, df$ID, FUN = function(x) +(1:nrow(df) >= min(which(x == 99))))
```

Comment: If STATUS column is missing a value, does the codes above have to be revised? I tried 2 of these and my FLAG column is blank. Looks like only the dplyr and tidyr combination takes account of the missing values.

Comment: All of the solutions work also with NA values. But if it's not working for you, please add an example of your data to be able to detect the problem.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `cummax` by group

```
df$FLAG <- with(df, ave(STATUS, ID, FUN = function(x) cummax(x == 99)))
df
#   ID STATUS FLAG
#1   1      0    0
#2   1      0    0
#3   1      0    0
#4   1      1    0
#5   1      1    0
#6   1      1    0
#7   1     99    1
#8   1     99    1
#9   1      1    1
#10  5      0    0
#11  5      1    0
```